# Is it possible to add transparency property to an object? [SOLVED]

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all!

I'm trying to model a glass wall for a robotics cell. Is there a way to set the material's transparency within a urdf model?

Thank you!!!

EDIT:

Thank you Peter, your reply was very helpful.
I solved the problem using GreyTransparent.

I have edited my urdf adding the following lines:

```
<gazebo reference="back_wall1">
    <material>Gazebo/GreyTransparent</material>
</gazebo>
```

Anyway, I found that there are other colors in gazebo.materials

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14465/is-it-possible-to-add-transparency-property-to-an-object?-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [nico_lauda](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2653/nico_lauda/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-09-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

UPDATE:

In gazebo 11 it seems the "a" argument to diffuse and friends don't work. You can still used material scripts, but another option is to use the "transparency" element of "visual"

http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=visual#visual_transparency

OLD ANSWER

Yes there is. Not sure if there's something within urdf, but it's certainly supported in sdf. In other words, you may have to put it in the `<gazebo>` tags.

[Here's the relavent documentation](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=material)

I often use `<diffuse>`, `<specular>`,`<emissive>`. Which each take rgba. However, you could also use some of the built in materials:

```
<material>
  <script>
    <name>Gazebo/BlueTransparent</name>
    <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
  </script>
</material>
```

Finally, you can make your own texture. See ThomasK's excellent answer here:

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1500/can-textures-be-added-to-simple-objects-from-my-own-source/

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2